# javascript DOM window onload

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm doing some programming in DOM, a Dice game. If I want to build a function to open a new window for the HTML code on button click how do i do that?

I want list windows.onload (when button icon-dice is clicked) to load a new window.

```
        <div id="page-menu-wrapper">

            <ul>

                <li id="icon-dice"></li>
```

Comment: [Welcome to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please provide the code you've tried so far and explain what is causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");` 
Also, I would suggest searching for similar questions first on Stackoverflow